# How to check/uncheck a checkbox while clicking a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to check/uncheck a checkbox that exist inside a row under table body when it is clicked anywhere within a row except a link. I tried to make it working by using jQuery's prop, but something is not working properly.

I have a table structure like below:

```
<table id="anywhere_click">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" onclick="selectAll('myDataID[]');" /></th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Details</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="myDataID[]" value="1" /></td>
        <td>Stackoverflow</td>
        <td>Some text here....</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="myDataID[]" value="2" /></td>
        <td>Google</td>
        <td>
            <a href="aaa.html">This is a Link</a><br />
            Some text here....<br />
            <img src="something.jpg" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="myDataID[]" value="3" /></td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>Some text here....</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: please post your jquery code here also

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#anywhere_click tbody tr').click(function (e) {
    if(!$(e.target).is('#anywhere_click td input:checkbox'))
    $(this).find('input:checkbox').trigger('click');
});

$('#anywhere_click tr a').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Your demo does not work exactly like I wanted. It is supposed to be working only when the table row under table body is clicked. In your example, table row located in table head is also trigerring the function. Furthermore, when I click directly on checkbox it is not working.

Comment: This also have same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you checked when the site 's loading.

You have to add in the tag `<td><input type="checkbox" name="myDataID[]" value="3" /></td>`
checked.

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="myDataID[]" value="3" checked /></td>
```

With the button you want checked and unchecked.

Info: [Information](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp)

and example: [Examble with button checked and unchecked](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_checkbox_checked)